# What are these Technic "Zapfen" ("stoppers") called in English?

Tags: technic, part-identification

[image: A pile of "Zapfen" pieces.]

What are these pieces called in English? Google translator doesn't help in this case...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The LEGO Pick A Brick store lists them as **connector pegs** (or, more simply, **pegs**) although they are more commonly known as **pins** in the fan community<sup>1</sup>.

The black ones have added friction for holding things together, while the light gray and beige ones are smoother and allow pieces to rotate, for example tires or beams.

[image]

<sup>1</sup> [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=139), [Peeron](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/4459)

Comment: I can't bring myself to edit this, so I'll just critique. I have more often seen those refered to as "pins" than "pegs". Just a suggestion.

Comment: LDraw uses "pin" consistently, which is why it's more used by fans, but LEGO does indeed call them pegs (with less consistency, considering the 1 1/2 is a "bush")

Comment: @Joubarc: Ah, I was wondering where the term "pin" came from.

Comment: At the time LDraw was started, internal LEGO names weren't publicly available, so James Jessiman had to start from scratch. I feel that he, and the ones who continued to expand LDraw after him, have done a way better job than LEGO; but on the other hand LEGO had no real reason to use an English-coherent naming scheme.